# how to extract test log from MTM ?

Tags: file, testing, logging, extract, mtm

I'm testing a project and all my test cases are in MTM , I'm looking for a way to extract all the test result we have in the MTM in a separate file , is there any way to do that ? please share if you have any idea
thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to export the results of an automated run, you can download the `.trx` (test run execution) file from the attachments section and use `XSL`and `XSLT` to create an html report from it (you can also use the command-line tool `tcm.exe run /export` to get a .trx file).

But if you created the test run by manual execution, this won't be possible. The only way to get a "result file" would be to parse the result of the test run using the TFS API (in C# or Powershell via `TfsTeamProjectCollection` from `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client` and store it in a file.

Or you can use the TFS Rest-API with this PowerShell-Script (save as .ps) which lets you query a JSON and extract the data you want and display it the way you want to:

```
$RunId = Read-Host -Prompt "TFS Run Id"

$Url = "http://<tfsurl>/tfs/<CollectionName>/<TeamProject>/_apis/test/runs/$RunId/results"

$Client = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$Client.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("<username>", "<password>", "<domain>")
$Json = $Client.DownloadString($Url) | ConvertFrom-Json

$Dict = @{}
ForEach($Test in $Json.value)
{
    $Key = "Run " + $Test.testRun.name + " [" + $Test.testRun.id + "]"
    $Val = $Test.testCase.name + " [" + $Test.testCase.id + "]" + " = " + $Test.outcome

    if (!$Dict.ContainsKey($Key))
    {
        $List = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
        $Dict.Add($Key, $List)
    }

    $IgnoreIndex = $Dict[$Key].Add($Val)
}

ForEach($Key in $Dict.Keys)
{
    Write-Host $Key
    ForEach($Val in $Dict[$Key])
    {
        Write-Host $Val
    }
}

Exit
```

(replace values like <xxx> with yours)